# For all $\phi$, $\phi \in \Gamma^{*}$ if and only if $\Gamma^{*} \vdash \phi$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

Do you find my reasoning valid?

**Let $\Gamma^{*}$ be a maximally consistent set of formulas. The, for all $\phi$, $\phi \in \Gamma^{*}$ if and only if $\Gamma^{*} \vdash \phi$**

Proof:

$(\to)$ Suppose $\phi \in \Gamma^{*}$. As $\Gamma^{*}$ is maximally consistent it clearly follows that there exists a derivation from $\Gamma^{*}$ to $\phi$, which is to say $\Gamma^{*} \vdash \phi$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $\Gamma^{*} \vdash \phi$. Let $U=\Gamma^{*} \cup \{\phi\}$. Then $\Gamma^{*} \subseteq U$. It follows from the definition of maximally consistency that $\Gamma^{*}=U$ if we can show that $U$ is consistent. For this, we use proof by contradiction. Assume therefore that $U \vdash \bot$. In that case we should have a derivation of $\bot$ from the assumptions which are either $\phi$ or formulas in $\Gamma^{*}$. Since $\Gamma^{*} \vdash \phi$, any assumptions of $\phi$ can be replaced by with derivations of $\phi$ from $\Gamma^{*}$ Thus, we are able to construct a derivation of $\bot$ from $\Gamma^{*}$, which is impossible since $\Gamma^{*}$ is consistent. Hence, $\phi \in \Gamma^{*}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for $(\rightarrow)$ is too complicated. From $\phi \in \Gamma^*$ it follows immediately, by definition of $\vdash$, that $\Gamma^* \vdash \phi$. So maximal consistency of $\Gamma^*$ is not needed.

Comment: So, I take it that it is redundant to invoke proof by contradiction? Well, it is good to know that even tutors are humans.